# Postgres connection failing

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssl, networking, virtualbox

Trying to connect to a remote vm database via port forwarding. The VM host is a remote server (Ubuntu x64), guest VM is Ubuntu x64, and port forwarding is set up for 15432 => 5432 (host => guest).

When I try to connect via psql or pgAdmin3, I get a connection refused error.

psql command from local machine:

```
psql -h remote.server.address -p 15432 -U postgres database_name
```

response:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

postgresql.conf listen_addresses is set to all:

```
$ cat /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf | grep listen
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

My pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             10.0.0.0/16            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5

host    informatics     nmr_user         192.168.20.223/32          md5
host    all         all         192.168.8.0/22          md5
host    all         all         192.168.50.0/24         md5
host    all         all         192.168.7.0/24          md5
host    all         all         192.168.4.0/24          md5
host    all         all         192.168.6.0/24          md5
```

SSL certs exist at the paths specified in pg_hba.conf
Restarting the postgres service also doesn't fix the problem

Pretty sure my problem is in pg_hba. I'm a networking amateur. On the vm:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state      UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:9a:8e:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9a:8ec6/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

**Edit: Solved**

The problem was not the postgres configuration, but the Virtualbox VM configuration on the remote host. Port forwarding was set up using NAT with the host listening on 127.0.0.1:15432. Because it was only listening on loopback interface, outside world saw port 15432 as closed. Once NAT was changed to 0.0.0.0:15432 on the host, the port was open and connections went through.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Anything interesting in the Postgres log file?

Comment: Doing a log `tail` while trying to connect show no new log entries in main.log or main.log.1 ...  it could be that the host is not accepting connections on port 15432, but how would i verify/fix that?

Comment: Is there a firewall in your machine?

Comment: @chalitha no firewall, see above for solution

Comment: What exactly did you change?  In my vagrantfile I opened the port with `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host: 5432, guest: 5432` and I am having the same auth failure you had.